# getting focus() inside a content editable div on tab

Tags: javascript

There is a main content editable div that displays certain templates with placeholders (underscores) - inside of which there may be other divs, also editable. The inside divs have a class - lets call it highlight.

I'd like to be able to tab through to the divs inside and type away.

I've given the inside divs a tabIndex which makes them tab-able but I'm not able to type unless I explicitly click them. I'd like to be able to do this using the keyboard only.

PS I need a JS solution, not Jquery

Replacing the inside divs with an input/ or text-area works perfectly, except, I'd like to use divs or spans

From another stackoverflow page, I attached an event listener, checking if the div had the class I was looking for, I called .blur() and .focus() on it explicitly - but that doesn't work

```
// partial code relevant to the problem

function contentEdit(text) {
    ....

    // replace placeholder text (underscores) with div
    // and maintain line breaks
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '<br/>')
        .replace(/[_]+/gm, '<div class="highlight" tabindex="0">  </div>');

    vm.content = '<div contenteditable>' + text + '</div>';

    var ce = document.getElementById('contenteditable-div');

    // tried this approach from stackoverflow
    ce.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            if (e.target.className == 'highlight') {
                e.target.blur();
                e.target.focus();
            }
        }
    });
    .......
}
```

The blur/ focus block only fires on the second time that condition is true - so, not on the first time a div of that condition is encountered.

Because of the tabIndex, the browser seems as if it's putting the focus on the div when tabbing through (there is a border highlight on it) but the input events don't fire unless you click the div. This is not the case with an input or a textarea - for some reason, they too come into focus but also take key inputs.

demo:  codepen.io/anon/pen/bPEJjo

Any ideas/ suggestions why the inner div can't accept keyboard events or how to get them firing?

Answer (score 2):

Listen keyup (better timing than with keydown) on the parent only, it'll bubble up from the child elements. Then create a range to the focused element and set the cursor to its position. Something like below:

```js
function moveCursor(e) {
    if (e.key !== 'Tab') {return;}
    var element = document.activeElement,
        range = document.createRange(),
        selection = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(element, 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    element.focus();
}
document.getElementById('pad').addEventListener('keyup', moveCursor);
```

```css
.ce {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="pad" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="ce" tabindex="1"></div>
  <div class="ce" tabindex="2"></div>
  <div class="ce" tabindex="3"></div>
  <div class="ce" tabindex="4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite working or what I was looking for in terms of functionality - I made a demo in codepen to better explain what I'm trying to do: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPEJjo

Comment: It is an answer to your question, you can apply it to your code.